# Continuity of a functional with respect to two different norms

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $J$ be a functional defined on $E = C^1[a,b]$ by
$$J(y) = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + (y^{\prime}(x))^2} \, dx.$$

Define the following two norms on $E$:

$$\|y\|_{\infty} = \max_{a\leq x\leq b} |y(x)|$$
$$\|y\|_{\ast} = \|y\|_{\infty} + \|y^{\prime}\|_{\infty}.$$

Then I'm to show that $J$ is continuous on $(E, ||\cdot||_{\ast})$ but not $(E, \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$.

First question. As far as I can tell, the first proof should be routine. Start with $(y_n)$ cauchy and choose $\epsilon$, then pick $N$ such that

$$||y_n - y_m||_{\ast} < \epsilon$$

for all $n,m > N$. Then find $\delta$ such that

$$|J(y_n) - J(y_m)| < \delta.$$

However, I'm completely blanking on how to manipulate the expanded expression

$$\left|\int_a^b \sqrt{1 - y_n^{\prime}}dx - \int_a^b \sqrt{1 - y_m^{\prime}}dx\right|.$$

Second question: I know that all I need to do to prove that $J$ is discontinuous in the other norm is provide a counterexample, but how on earth do I generate one? Am I just supposed to intuit the form of a counterexample or is there some strategy for producing one here?

Comment: It suffices to show that it is (or isn't) continuous at $0$.

Comment: So if the functional is continuous at 0, it's continuous everywhere? What conditions make this true? Sorry if I'm clearly forgetting a basic result.

Comment: Sorry, this is true only if the map in question is a linear map between two normed spaces, as the norm is not a linear map, you can ignore my statement.

Comment: Don't worry, I made almost the same mistake earlier when I tried to combine the integrals using the little-known linearity property of the square root symbol... When I realized that didn't work is when I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show continuity in the norm $\|\cdot\|_*$ you can take advantage of the uniform continuity of the function $f(z) = \sqrt{1+z^2}$ on a compact set.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $y_1(x) \in C^1$ then $y_1'[a,b]$ is a compact set as is $$B = \{ z \in \mathbb{R} : |z-w| \le 1 \text{ for some } w \in y_1'[a,b] \}.$$ $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B$ which means there is a $1 > \delta > 0$ such that if $z,w \in B$ and $|z-w| < \delta$ then $|f(z)-f(w)| < \epsilon$.

Now let $y_2(x)$ be such that $$\|y_1 - y_2 \|_* < \delta.$$ Since $\delta < 1$ we have $y_2'(x) \in B$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, since $|y_1'(x) - y_2'(x)| < \delta < 1$ for all $x$. Hence $$\left|\int_a^b \sqrt{1+y_1'(x)^2}dx - \int_a^b \sqrt{1+y_2'(x)^2}dx\right| < (b-a) \epsilon$$

---

As for the counter example, the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ gives no control over the derivative, whereas the norm $\|\cdot\|_*$ does. So now consider the function $y_1(x)=0$ for which $J(y_1) = b-a$. Now we wish to construct a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converge to $y_1$.

Notice that $J$ is the arc length of the curve. Try to find a counter example with $\sin(x)$ such as $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin(nx)$$

Here the amplitude of $f_n$ goes to zero, so it converges in the infinity norm. However, if the frequencies of $\sin(nx)$ increase fast enough (maybe with $n^2x$ in the argument even) then the arc length will get very large.

Comment: Apologies for the edit. Realize a fundamental mistake as I was going to sleep.

Comment: Why is $B$ a compact set?

Comment: @ImHackingXD, since $y_1$ is in C^1, this means $y_1’$ is continuous. The interval [a,b] is compact, and hence, $y_1’[a,b]$ is compact, since it is the continuous image of a compact set.

Comment: thank you for replying even though this is a very old question. I understand perfectly what you said, what isn't obvious to me is that $y_1^{\prime}[a,b]$ being compact implies $B$ is compact.